# Execute binary file on android API 31 and 32

Tags: java, android, processbuilder

I have executable files made through the tool-chain via the rust platform.
which is right now arm arch supported.

now my code snipers as per below

```
 try {
        File binFilePath1 = new File(getFilesDir() + Util.BinPath);

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command(pluginFilePath.getCanonicalPath(), "-c", pingPath.getCanonicalPath(), "-lp"
                , binFilePath1.getCanonicalPath(), "-o", resultPath.getCanonicalPath());

        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        Log.i("", process.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

so basically my command is
./plugintest -c in.conf -lp /data/data/***.****.*****/files/bin/lib -o results.txt

It smoothly works on android API 24,25

But when I try to load in android 31 / 32 API level it gives me an error like below

**System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/data/***.****.*****/files/verifier/bin/plugin-testapp": error=13, Permission denied**

- try all permission but with any of permission no luck.

Let me know if need more information.

Comment: That should be the cause: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission

Comment: @Robert so do you think if I change access location like external storage or anything else way to achieve it?

Comment: sdcard and external storage are always folders where apps can not execute something. The last path I know which you could try is `/data/local/tmp`. Note that apps can not list the content of this folder on Android 11+ but they should be able to write and may be execute (don't know, never tried from within an app). Alternative could be to pack the executables into the matching `lib/arm64-v8a` folder in the APK so that they are getting extracted upon APK installation

Comment: Hey, @Robert thank you for instance replay let me try both ways and update.

Comment: hey, @Robert I try "could try is /data/local/tmp" but look like not accessible for read-write.
and another way "lib/arm64-v8a folder in the APK" got the same error as asked in the question.

Comment: So the only chance seems to be to set `android:targetSdkVersion` to 28 which of course prohibits APK distribution via PlayStore. Now I understand why Termux app is no longer updated in PlayStore...